# how to truncate a text to a given size in a worksheet cell using pear php

Tags: php, excel, pear, truncate, worksheet

Using using Pear worksheet PHP,
I would like to truncate a text in a worksheet cell.
For instance a large text like "lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..." could be truncated to a size of 4 like "Lorem..." but when selecting the cell the whole text can be read.

Answer (score 0):

I think this result can be achived this way, it's a matter of column widht:

When creating a worksheet the widht of the cell is defined by the first row of the excel file.
So if you create a first row with headers of the lenght of 4, then the other cells will have a width of 4. So if you put your entire text "Lorem ipsum..." in a cell you'll see only the begin of  the text.